# Eclipse - import code format settings

Tags: eclipse, jar, intellij-idea

Hi I was using intellij where I added code setting jar by following steps:

Import Settings and then point to this JAR. Then right click on the module and do "Reformat Code"

But now I am using same project in eclipse. How can I use above setting jar in clipse and format code ?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Dmitry Durkin answer.

You have to manually create new **formatter**(and/or **clean up**) profile which matches the one to one settings inside `settings.jar`. Hoping eclipse provides all the one to one mapping. Not take much time.

In eclipse go to `Window > Preferences`. Navigate to `Java > Code style > Formatter`. Here create new formatter which matches the settings in settings.jar.

Use this new formatter profile to create new clean up profile in `Java > Code style > Cleanup` for additional settings like `Removing trailing spaces` etc.

Right click on your project(s) and go to `Source > Clean up` or `Source > Format`. To clean up/format all your project(s) in one go.

Comment: If it answers your question then please accept it else edit your post and ask what you need more.

Comment: @AnupamSharma Mark the answer as accepted to avoid your post listed in unanswered posts list.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not support `settings.jar` from IntelliJ IDEA.

AFAIK there are no easy way to convert Idea code style settings (the actual `code.style.schemes.xml` file inside `settings.jar`) to eclipse. You have to migrate it somehow, probably with the help of 3rd party plugins.